# Can't download a file keep getting this error ERROR 404: Not Found

Tags: 14.04

I can't download this file: `http://bruteforce.gr/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-VERSION.tar.gz`. I don't why I keep on getting this error.

```
   wget http://bruteforce.gr/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-VERSION.tar.gz 
    --2017-02-01 20:13:35--  http://bruteforce.gr/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-VERSION.tar.gz
    Resolving bruteforce.gr (bruteforce.gr)... 217.70.180.137, 2001:4b98:dc0:950::137
    Connecting to bruteforce.gr (bruteforce.gr)|217.70.180.137|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2017-02-01 20:13:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: It seems for me, that this file simple doesn't exist, what you provided above.

Comment: He got the command from here: https://github.com/ikoniaris/kippo-graph

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't download it because such file does not exist, as you can see if you use any browser to access the link used in your command: *http://bruteforce.gr/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-VERSION.tar.gz*.

You can get the program you were looking for, Kippo-graph, here  instead:

- [Kippo-graph (0.9.3 version)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kippo-graph/)  at sourceforge.
- [Kippo-graph (1.5.1 version)](https://bruteforce.gr/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz), the latest version, at bruteforce.